# Problem with receiving a generator stream object in JavaScript from Python route (415 unsupported media type error)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, generator, openai-api

I am fairly new to handle generator object in Python?flask  and have a following problem with streaming the response from Flask server to Javascript frontend.

I have a Flask route defined like below, that fetches the response from OpenAI model and generates the result in form of token stream.
This route is triggered by button click (POST request). This works well, and I can see the tokens appear in Pyhon console.

```
@app.route('/send-to-chat', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def send_chat():
    global index

    data = request.get_json()
    text_input = data['text']
    context = data['ctx']
    lang = data['lang']
    vname = data['vname']
    vemail = data['vemail']
    words = data['words']

    response = get_chat_response(text_input, context, index, lang, vname,vemail, words)

    def generate():
        responseFull = ''

        for word in response:
            data = "data:"+word+"\n\n"
            #print(data)
            yield data


    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()),content_type='text/event-stream')
```

Then I would like to receive this stream data in JavaScript client. To accomplish this I use this code snippet:

```
var eventSource;

function startEventSource(user, code, previousText) {

  wordContainer = document.getElementById('chatbox');

  eventSource = new EventSource("/send-to-chat");

  eventSource.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("Connection established.");
  };

  eventSource.onerror = function(event) {
    if (event.target.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) {
      console.log("Connection closed with error. Attempting to reconnect...", event);
      // Attempt to reconnect after a delay.
      setTimeout(startEventSource, 5000);
    } else {
      console.error("Error occurred:", event);
    }
  };

  eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    wordContainer.innerHTML = previousText+'<br><br>'+event.data;
  };
}
```

However, I always get 415 error (media type not supported) and the connection is closed automatically.
I suspect I need to respond differently to POST (chat trigger) and GET methods (event stream) within my route, but I just can't find a proper way to do it. Any advice will be appreciated! Thank you!